# How can i check if String has Numbers sorted in ascending order like 1234?

Tags: c#, string, numbers

For my homework I have to create a program that scans the user input "password" and shows if it is strong or weak.

One of my conditions is to check if the string Password contains numbers in a row, for example, mypass123.

I have already tried this but it wouldn't accept letters:

```
int DigitCounter = 0;
var DigitRow = string.Join("", Password.OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i.ToString())));

for(int i = 0; i < Password.Length; ++i)
{
    if(Password == DigitRow)
    {
        DigitCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the type of your Password?

Comment: its just a string

Comment: Do these passwords have "numbers sorted in ascending order": `"abc_1"`, `"12"`, `"1_ab_2_cd_3"`, `"ab_12_cd"`, `"1_2_3"`, `"ab_1235"`?

Comment: No, the user gets to input the password and the program checks it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach with regex expression:

```
foreach (var numberGroup in new Regex("[0-9]{2,}").Matches(Password))
{
    if (numberGroup.Value.OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEquals(numberGroup.Value))
    {
         // numbers in ascending order!
    }
}
```

`[0-9]{2,}` will match every part of input string that contains two or more digits next to each other. Then we try to sort the input string by digits and see if the string has changed - if it didn't it contained digits in order already

Comment: Thank you i will try it

Comment: this looks buggy, you're never using numberGroup

Comment: `if (numberGroup.Value.OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEquals(numberGroup.Value)) {/* number group in ascending order*/}`

Comment: Thanks @DmitryBychenko - edited my answer according to your suggestion

Comment: This answer does not check if it is in a row. For example, it matches `1234` but also matches `0279`.

Answer (score 0):

Each character in a string can be converted to a number, depends on the encoding.
In ASCII, `A` is 65, `B` is 66, etc. You can get them by casting them to int (`(int) Password[0]`) and compare between them.

```
Password = "12345";
var array = Password.Select(i => (int) i).ToList();
// array: { 49, 50, 51, 52, 53 }
// Use your way to check if they are in a row!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below function

```
 public static bool IsStrong(string pass)
        {

            bool isStrong = false;
            int num = 0;
            var stringArr = pass.ToCharArray();
            var numsArr = new List<int>();

            foreach (var a in stringArr)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(a.ToString(), out num))
                {
                    numsArr.Add(num);
                }
            }

            if (numsArr.Any())
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < numsArr.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if(numsArr[i] - numsArr[i-1] != 1)
                    {
                        isStrong = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return isStrong;

        }
```